# Two asterisks followed by a comma

Tags: support

As I was typing an answer I realized that I cannot type **, in main answer window.  I was watching the preview window while typing **, and I could see only one asterisk and a comma.  That is, in the preview window I see *, instead of **,.  I tried "**", then in the preview window I see "*",.
The only way out was to include a space between ** and the comma.  That is, if I type ** , then I can see ** , in the preview window.

Even here, the preview window acts strangely.  The above paragraph is unreadable in the preview window. If I retype only the first sentence (of the above paragraph) then the two asterisks and the comma shows up fine. See below.

As I was typing an answer I realized that I cannot type **, in main answer window.

Does ** has a special assignment in an answer window?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

** is Markdown syntax for bold text, **text** gives **text**.

* is for italic text, *text* gives *text*.

So, if you type simply asterisks, you would see the formatting in the preview change. However, you can escape the meaning by a backslash, as I did here: `\*\*`.

Comment: Is there a way to type asterisks? Such as \**?

Comment: Apparently, I answered my own question. :)